# Retrieving the images in Mysql DB and display using java

Tags: java, database, image, using

I have a Mysql database with the images in it.

Now I want to retreive this database and display the images in a web page using java code.

Can anyone provide the code for this?? 
Atleast suggestions to do this???

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: How are the images in the database? Blobs? File names?

Comment: @Bart: yeah..i have used blobs only...

Answer (score 0):

Create a servlet to handle this. Lets call it `ImageServlet` with the URL path `/Image`

Write code in the `doGet` method of the servlet to read a parameter called, say, `name` from the request and execute an SQL.

The SQL should fetch the blob from your table. I can't remember the syntax, but ultimately you will end up with a `byte[]` which you'll have to write into your response stream.

In your JSP, you will invoke it like this:

`<img src="/Image?name=logo.jpg" />`

This links below should get you started writing SQLs to read from blobs:

http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1325

http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html#ImageServletServingFromDatabase - with due credit to [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)

Comment: Hey Ya..!! I tried this way,i am getting an internal exception.. I think my sql command is not executing.If u need,i will provide the code i am trying now also...   Also the links you have given are not related to the sql. Thanks anyways..!!